# rviz high dpi issue

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm having issues on high dpi screen using rviz.
It seemes that the 3d rendering object doesn't scale properly, and each dimension is half the dimension he should be.
[image: image description]

I'm using ubuntu (kubuntu) 16.04. Rviz is updated to the lst version

ros-kinetic-rviz:
Installato: 1.12.4-0xenial-20161027-160750-0700

The screen is using a scaling of 2x

Maybe is related to this?
http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=88902

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249914/rviz-high-dpi-issue/) by [Boris_il_forte](https://answers.ros.org/users/8606/boris_il_forte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2016-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this might be fixed now:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1069#issuecomment-298136551

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/1078

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0